# How to get gradle to publish to a local meven repo

Tags: android, maven, gradle, build.gradle

I've created a simple sample library using Android Studio.

My goal is that when building the module, it publishes it to a maven repo on the local file system to be consumed by another process.

I've followed the instructions from https://developer.android.com/build/publish-library/upload-library, and arrived at the following build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.mylibbrary'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 26

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    publishing {
        singleVariant("debug")
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        debug(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'com.example'
            artifactId = 'mylibbrary'
            version = "1.0"

            afterEvaluate {
                from components.debug
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = 'mynewrepo'
            url = "file://${project.buildDir}/repo"
        }
    }
}
```

However, it seems that the publish task for this gradle file never actually runs when building the module, despite mylibbrary-debug.aar ending up in MyLibrary\mylibbrary\build\outputs\aar.

How can I get this to publish to the repo in MyLibrary\mylibbrary\build\repo\mynewrepo?

Comment: Have you run the publish(if I am not mistaken,the task called publish) task  ?

Comment: I added an "assembleDebugAndroidTest.finalizedBy publishDebugPublicationToMynewrepoRepository", and it published without issue. Wasn't aware that was part of the requirements as its not mentioned in the docs.

Comment: @Rob If you'd like to add this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Ok) I will add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run "publish" Task

Add "assembleDebugAndroidTest.finalizedBy publishDebugPublicationToMynewrepoRepository"